# Add a widget to the Content zone

Tags: orchardcms

I need to add a breadcrumb nav to my site, the problem is that the designer laid out the site so that it is among the fields of the content items. I added a Breadcrumb Zone to my theme and called it from the Layout.cshtml file. First I tried creating new zones in Layout.cshtml and moving the fields out of the local content zone into these new zones (using placement.info), but due to the complexity of the site that got too complicated.

Is there a way to place a widget into a local zone? I've been around in circles on this for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and then realized I hadn't posted my question yet. It turns out that the widget zones can be used in local zones! In the local zone, you just put `@Display(Layout.ZoneName)` where ZoneName is the name of your zone. Simple as that. [Source](http://www.bluesphereinc.com/blog/orchard-theming-tips-and-tricks).